# what tool or theory should I use to analyse Baccarat roadmap?

Tags: data-science-model

I am going to write a program to analyze the result of the Baccarat game.

In Baccarat, there will be two results, banker win, and player win.

People use a roadmap to record the results, it's like this:

[image]

The red circles represent banker win and blue circles represent player win.

I want to model the data structure and then try to analyze is there some pattern or rule that the results will follow.

I want to ask in data science are there some existing theories for me to use to analyze this kind of map?

Comment: this is somewhat broad, depending on how you approach or model the problem different tools can be used. For example if modelled as matrix of moves, various tools like PCA can be used.

Comment: My main purpose is to predict the result of the next bet according the existing results.